# Laravel & CKEditor - Return with editor old value

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

I'm validating the editor content on my controller and i want to return the user back to the editor view if its content length is less than 30 characters. Either way, this piece of code:

```
<textarea name="text-editor" id="text-editor" value="{{ old('text-editor') }}"></textarea>
```

Does not work because all of the things that CKEditor javascript script does. So, is there a way to put back the editors content when the user writes less than 30 characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place old value between tags because `textarea` [does not have](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp) `value` property -
`<textarea name="text-editor" id="text-editor">{{ old('text-editor') }}</textarea>`

Comment: Omg. That's obvious. I feel so stupid right now. Thanks for pointing that out!